# How to trigger conditional rendering with value from AsyncStorage in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am using React Native to build an app and I am struggling with conditional rendering. I want to have a tutorial screen, shown only the first time the user opens the app. After that, it shouldn't be shown anymore. On the tutorial, there is a button "Get started" that should trigger to go to the app. Pressing the button saves in AsyncStorage "showTutorial" to false, so next time it won't show. However, pressing the button does not hide the tutorial and go to the main app, only if i reopen the app, save the file (working in VSCode) or reload the app then it refreshes and the tutorial page is not shown anymore. I don't understand why does this not work, specifically why doesn't the state variable change and trigger the other screen.

Local storage is updated when pressing the button with the correct value based on the logs.

So how can I achieve going to the main app directly after pressing the button?

app-navigation.js:

```
const [showTutorial, setShowTutorial] = React.useState(true);

const getShowTutorial = async () => {
    try {
        const LS_showTutorial = await AsyncStorage.getItem('showTutorial');
        if (LS_showTutorial !== null) {
            setShowTutorial(JSON.parse(LS_showTutorial));
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Failed to fetch the data from storage', error);
    }
};

React.useEffect(() => {
    getShowTutorial();
}, []);

return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        { showTutorial ? ( // THIS DOES NOT CHANGE WHEN PRESSING THE BUTTON
            <TutorialScreen/>
        ) : (
            <DashboardScreen/>
        )}
    </View>
);
```

tutorial.js

```
const saveData = async (key, value) => {
    try {
        console.log('Saving local data with ', key, ' and ', JSON.stringify(value));
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Something went wrong', error);
    }
};

return (
    <View style={styles.basicContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.textTitle}>
            Hello world!
        </Text>
        <Button
            onPress={() => {
                saveData('showTutorial', false);
            }}
        >Get started</Button>
    </View>
);
```

P.S. Tested only on Android emulator and physical device.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is you're not using async/await for the invocation of `getShowTutorial` in the `useEffect`. As a result, the component in app-navigation.js renders before the value in `AsyncStorage` can be retrieved. This article explains the idea behind awaiting asynchronous code in `useEffect`. https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-use-async-function-in-react-hook-useeffect-typescript-js-6204a788a435

Try something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  (
    async function () {
      await getShowTutorial()
    }
  )()
}, [])
```

Also, try using await/async with the `onPress` handler:

```
onPress={async () => {await saveData('showTutorial', false)}}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I tried your suggestions and didn't help. It works the same as before.

Comment: For this part: 
`if (LS_showTutorial !== null) {
            setShowTutorial(JSON.parse(LS_showTutorial));
        }`
does `JSON.parse(LS_showTutorial) === false` and not `"false"`? If you're setting that to a string it will evaluate as truthy which would explain why it's not working

Comment: JSON.parse returns the boolean `false` from the string `"false"`. I double checked and it is indeed `false` as boolean at `setShowTutorial(JSON.parse(LS_showTutorial))`. The problem is not the function itself, if I reload the app or save the file, this function runs correctly and the tutorial page disappears. However, it does not enter the function when I press the button.